# How to get access to the parameters in PCL from UWP in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am working with the Xamarin Forms in combination with the I2C devices and the Raspberry Pi. I programmed in C# and the Raspberry Pi was installed with Windows IoT. And I have encountered a problem about the parameter access.

I have a microtimer in the UWP project and I want to read the data from the analog input every 100ms. In the OnTimedEvent, there is a caculation which requires the some parameters which are set in the PCL project,the namespace is "I2CADDA.MainPage.xaml.cs". I tried to set these parameters as public static.

```
public static double gainFactor = 1;
public static double gainVD = 1;
```

And in the UWP project , I use the dependency service because I have to use the micro timer, so the realization of the interface is done in "I2CADDA.UWP.MainPage.xaml.cs", in the function OnTimedEvent, I tried to get the parameters from PCL project file.

```
public void OnTimedEvent(object sender, MicroLibrary.MicroTimerEventArgs timerEventArgs)
        {

            byte[] readBuf = new byte[2];
            I2CDevice.ReadI2C(chan, readBuf); //read voltage data from analog to digital converter
            sbyte high = (sbyte)readBuf[0];
            int mvolt = high * 16 + readBuf[1] / 16;
            val = mvolt / 204.7 + inputOffset;
            val = val / gainFactor / gainVD; //gainFactor and gainVD shows not exist in current context

        }
```

It seems that the UWP project can not have access to the PCL project in normal way. May I ask how can I solve this problem? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, to call a static Field, you should use the class name to call it,

In your code, the static Fields are in the I2CADDA.MainPage.xaml.cs, and for instance, they are in the `I2CADDA.MainPage` class, you can call the field as

```
double Factor = I2CADDA.MainPage.gainFactor;
double VD = I2CADDA.MainPage.gainVD;
```

So your above code should be like this:

```
public void OnTimedEvent(object sender, MicroLibrary.MicroTimerEventArgs timerEventArgs)
{

    byte[] readBuf = new byte[2];
    I2CDevice.ReadI2C(chan, readBuf); //read voltage data from analog to digital converter
    sbyte high = (sbyte)readBuf[0];
    int mvolt = high * 16 + readBuf[1] / 16;
    val = mvolt / 204.7 + inputOffset;
    val = val / I2CADDA.MainPage.gainFactor / I2CADDA.MainPage.gainVD; 
}
```

Please also make sure you have reference the PCL in your UWP project.